# Responsive background on Wordpress with Sage theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I have read a lot of articles and a lot of options, and I have tried almost everything that I was able to find on the internet and yet I cannot reach the effect that I want. And the effect that I want is to have a responsive background image, that shows the whole part of the image on every device. With all solutions currently that I am trying, the effect is the same, and on small device the Profile image of the lady is not full. So I start to think that I should not use that specific image, or I need to modify it.
Here you can see example of the running site:
http://biserka.onesto.bg/bg/home/

As I mentioned what I want is the lady profile to be visible all the time, and not to shrink so ugly. The latest solution that I have tried was to add row in container-fluid element from Bootstrap 3. I have tried to add the image as CSS of the background, I have tried to add it as img tag inside container, and nothing helps me to get the desired effect.

Here is and my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
  <?php get_template_part('templates/head'); ?>


  <body  <?php body_class(); ?>>

  <div class="biserka-site-content ">
      <div class="wrap container-fluid ">
        <div class="row custom-background">

          </div>

      </div>

 <!-- rest of the site -->
   </div>
</body>
```

and the css for the background:

```
.custom-background {

    background:url(<?php echo $image; ?>);

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;


    /* Background image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
    background-position: center 82px;

    /* Background image doesn't tile */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    /* Background image is fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when
       the content's height is greater than the image's height */
    background-attachment: fixed;

    /* This is what makes the background image rescale based
       on the container's size */
    background-size: cover;

    /* Set a background color that will be displayed
       while the background image is loading */
    background-color: white;
  }
```

Thank you in advance for your ideas and the help!

Best regards,
Mario Pavlov.

Comment: you can try to align the image to right - background-position: right 82px;

Comment: I have tried with right background position, still no success

Comment: You need `background-size: contain;` to have the lady always visible, image always be "contained" and not cropped. But like that, and with a `no-repeat`, it could not fill all the area, unlike `background-size: cover;`